# What's better of require(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'myParent.php') than just require('myParent.php')?

Tags: php, include, require

Lots of famous PHP scripts including WordPress use `dirname(__FILE__).'/myParent.php'` instead of just `'myParent.php'` when including files in the same directory of the currently running script.

Aren't they the same thing? Why do you prefer typing more?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should always prefer `__DIR__` as a replacement for `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: \_\_DIR\__ is supported as of PHP 5.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PHP needs to know the absolute path to the file. `dirname(__FILE__).'/myParent.php'` already is the absolute path but `'myParent.php'` requires a lookup using the given paths in [*include_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) to get an absolute path and find the file. A better choice would be `'./myParent.php'`:

> However, it is more efficient to explicitly use `include './file'` than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

Comment: An absolute path is not required, and the include path isn't necessarily needed.  "If a path is defined (full or relative), the include_path will be ignored altogether." http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @Justin Johnson: With *path* the manual probably means that the string contains at least one `/`. So `./foo`, `foo/bar`, `/foo/bar` are paths but `foo` is not. And that does also apply for `myParent.php`.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this `require dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/out/DBconnection.php";` ? I want something like `./` or `../../`. Is there?

Answer (score 14):

Besides the performance increase (which is likely a pre-optimization in most cases*), it also protects from the (very odd) scenario where the environment's PHP configuration does not have the current directory (`.`) as part of the include path.

* Benchmark of `include` using a path that requires `include_path` lookup versus a relative path that does not.  Tested over 100000 iterations each

Results

```
include("include.php"):   8.3664200305939s
include("./include.php"): 8.3511519432068s

(8.3664200305939 - 8.3511519432068) / 100000 = 0.000000152680874s
```

Unless you're including hundreds or thousands of files, 0.0000001s is negligible at best.

Test code

```
define("MAX", 100000);

ob_start();
$i = MAX;
$_t = microtime(true);
do {
    include("include.php");
} while ( --$i );
$_t = microtime(true) - $_t;
ob_end_clean();

echo "include(\"include.php\"):  {$_t}s\n";

ob_start();
$i = MAX;
$_t = microtime(true);
do {
    include("./include.php");
} while ( --$i );
$_t = microtime(true) - $_t;
ob_end_clean();
```

Test was conducted on a 2.16GHz Macbook 10.5.8 with PHP Version 5.2.9 (www.entropy.ch Release 7)

Comment: Here are results of my tests with more ways to do the includes:
```100.0% - include(__DIR__ . "/include.php"): 3.1468150615692s```


```118.1% - include("./include.php"): 3.7181701660156s```


```154.6% - include("include.php"): 4.8651170730591s```


```162.8% - include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/include.php"): 5.1241970062256s```

Answer (score 12):

Using dirname + file name is slightly faster, because PHP will not iterate through *include_path* searching for the file. If speed matters, you will likely type more.

Answer (score 8):

An added note about include('./file.php').

If only speed matters, then yes you can use include('./file.php'), but if you want to resolve dependencies and relative paths issues, you're better off using dirname(__ FILE __), because

```
include('./file.php')
```

will still construct paths relative to the executing script (the **including** script), while

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php');
```

will resolve paths relative to the current script where this line resides (the **included** script).

Generally, you're better off using dirname(__ FILE __ ), since './' only gives a negligible performance increase while dirname(__ FILE __ ) gives you a lot more reliable include.

/EDIT: Also note that the benchmark done above only concerns `include('./something.php')`, which indeed is faster than `include('something.php')` because you don't have the include_path walking, but when you use `dirname(__FILE__)` you get the `dirname()` function call overhead, which makes it slower than walking the include_path (unless you have a lot paths in your include_path).

Comment: or `__DIR__` (which saves a `dirname()` call)

Comment: Yes but `__DIR__` is only available since PHP 5.3.0 when `__FILE__` and `dirname()` are both available since PHP 4.0.2. `__DIR__` is more call-efficient, but less retrocompatible :/