# Include php file

Tags: php, linux, include

I have the following directory tree on a linux server:

```
/home/control-center/back-office/php/average.php
/home/control-center/front-office/db.php
```

db.php contains the database connection information.

When I try to execute average.php, I get the following error message:

```
PHP Warning: include(../../front-office/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/control-center/back-office/php/average.php on line 18

PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../front-office/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/control-center/back-office/php/average.php on line 18
```

Should I include something else in my script so it would work? I found a couple of similar cases on the Internet, but I haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: Your path isn't correct

Comment: could you please paste the complete code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../front-office/db.php';`

`dirname(__FILE__)` returns the absolute path of the current file. This ensures that you get the correct path relative to the current file.

Your problem is often encountered when the current script was included by another script. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628471/926073) which is related to what I mentioned.

Comment: Please expand your answer to say _why_ this might help. (Be aware that this is currently a poorly-asked question; working out what is really from the description provided might be quite difficult…)

Answer (score 0):

How do you include these 2 pages in your avarage.php file?

if you want to include header.php in index.php page  which is in "sample" folder (sample/index.php) and header.php in include/header.php, then you have to write "../" before including a directory, so that would be like:

```
include '../include/header.php';
```