# PHP background execution not working with include files

Tags: php

This is my code

sample.php

```
//Background execution
function execInBackground($cmd)
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") {
        pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));
    } else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
    }
}
```

and

```
execInBackground('php -f ' . SITE_PATH . 'admin/background_process.php live_import');
```

background_process.php

```
if($argv[1]=='live_import') {
...
...  
some functionalities
}
```

Its working fine, but in background_process.php, If I include another file like
background_process.php

```
if($argv[1]=='live_import') {
   include_once('new.php');
}
```

In new.php, I have code for functionalities. But this is not working.

Comment: Did you know the term: *workingdirectory* and show your errors if you have any...

Comment: Read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/why-would-i-use-dirname-file-in-an-include-or-include-once-statement