# file_exists is not work !(php)

Tags: php, file, exists, file-exists

this code is correct and returned True

```
if (file_exists("./up_dir/p57hekl77307hhHkkglkIp/01397678849965301.png")) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

but this code returned False !

```
$dir = $_POST["dir"];   // = p57hekl77307hhHkkglkIp
$name = $_POST["name"]; // = 013976788499653

if (file_exists("./up_dir/" . $dir . "/" . $name . "01.png")) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

please help

Comment: Check path is right or not

Comment: This code should work. If it doesn't, you're probably getting wrong values in `$dir` or `$name` (maybe a whitespace on the beginning/at the end).

Comment: what is this php file path?

Comment: `$dir=trim($_POST["dir"]);`
    `$name=trim($_POST["name"]);`  AND `file_exists("./up_dir/$dir/$name01.png")`

Comment: This might be a silly question but are both examples above being called from the same file?

Comment: yes both examples above being called from the same file

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
-path is right!

-$dir=trim($_POST["dir"]); $name=trim($_POST["name"]); AND file_exists("./up_dir/$dir/$name01.png")

i tested but not worked!

php file and path is Together

Comment: Verify number part is treated as string and not as number 0139... As 139...

Comment: Does it work if you use: `file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/up_dir/" . $dir . "/" . $name . "01.png")` ?

Comment: Have you checked the actual values in the POST array before using them?

Comment: error reporting will tell you if something's not kosher

Answer (score 0):

its work :)

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/up_dir/" . $dir . "/" . $name . "01.png")) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Thank RelaxedArcher for answer and other user for helping me

Comment: You probably included the second script in another one and called it from there. The "." is relative to the calling script, dirname is relative to the script in which it is being used. You can find more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/why-would-i-use-dirname-file-in-an-include-or-include-once-statement