# PHP Source Paths

Tags: php, directory

How do I start at the base directory of my folder when referencing files. I will give context. Also, I am aware of this question: [Why would I use dirname(__FILE__) in an include or include_once statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/why-would-i-use-dirname-file-in-an-include-or-include-once-statement) But this did not seem to work for me.

If you imagine I have the following directory

```
../main/
       index.php // main page
       /about
           index.php // about page
       /contact
           index.php //about apge
       /src
           /php
               header.php
```

If I was to open up `main/index.php` you would be presented with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "./src/php/header.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the above code will not work for `/about` etc as the path is not the same (I would need `"./../src/php/header.php"`. Is there anyway to *anchor* the file path to always start from `/main` that way, the code above would work for all.

I have tried to use __DIR__, but that did not seem to work:

For example, when I am trying to echo images, this is the URL I am getting `C:/xampp/htdocs/boot/src/img1_car.png`, `/boot/` is my *main*. Unfortunately the source is finding nothing, even though the image is in that position.

Comment: There is a difference between a server side file location and an URL. The URL could for instance be `http://localhost/src/img1_car.png` which could for instance be translated to `C:/xampp/htdocs/boot/src/img1_car.png` on the server. An URL is an abstraction. It doesn't have to point to an actual file. It can also be directed to a script that generates the image, for example. Currently, it's not really clear to me which kind of problem you are having. Do you have problems including files, or do you have problems with invalid urls?

Comment: This is not really an answer, but your question already took me two minutes to figure out. If you run into issues like this, that's mostly a sign of one of two things: trying to do something too complex without handy tools OR the codebase is an incredible mess. It seems to me that your codebase is okay, so you're probably trying to do something that's just hard in plain php. Have a look at a routing engine like https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router or maybe even a framework.

Comment: Tip: Switch to `require` instead of `include`, to get more clear error messages about which file is missing, if the problem is indeed about including files.

Comment: @Loek Thanks for the response. The issue I'm having is with consistency. `header.php` simply contains some HTML that is being echoed, like a very simple component. I want to be able to echo this on all pages. However, with `about/index.php` and `index.php` being in different directories, this means that the include has to change, depending on the directory. My aim is to have one include/require.