# PHP dirname(__FILE__) v/s ./

Tags: php

I found this code in a small script I'm modifying for my own use:

```
require dirname(__FILE__)."/GearmanManager.php";
```

I found it to be a bit strange, wouldn't

```
require "./GearmanManager.php";
```

do the exact same thing?

Comment: Second approach might cause `base_dir` problems when php.ini is configured to be safe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220443/whats-better-of-requiredirname-file-myparent-php-than-just-require, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628443/why-would-i-use-dirname-file-in-an-include-or-include-once-statement

Comment: Oh crap, nice catch Pang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `./` you're looking in the current working directory which might change. `dirname(__FILE__)` on the other hand won't change.

If you for instance change the working directory (using `chdir('/')` or similar) before the `require`, your first example will succeed whereas your second will fail.

[Excerpt from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220460/453331):

> However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

So if you know you're not going to be changing directory, `./` will be faster.