# include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Tags: php

Can someone help me out?

This is error I get when I uploaded a file into remote server, but on a localhost not so.

include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

**Error line**
include("http://x.com/public_html/y.info/output/include/Send_Message_variables.php");

Comment: The error message is straightforward: you need to change your configuration or use another function than `include()`. You can try cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: require_once(../x.info/output/include/x.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory    is the error I get when I uploaded the file to the server

Comment: see the [`dirname()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220443/whats-better-of-requiredirname-file-myparent-php-than-just-require) function to use an absolute path.